# Functor instance for generic polymorphic ADTs in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functor, category-theory

When it comes to applying category theory for generic programming Haskell does a very good job, for instance with libraries like `recursion-schemes`. However one thing I'm not sure of is how to create a generic functor instance for polymorphic types.

If you have a polymorphic type, like a List or a Tree, you can create a functor from (Hask × Hask) to Hask that represents them. For example:

```
data ListF a b = NilF | ConsF a b  -- L(A,B) = 1+A×B
data TreeF a b = EmptyF | NodeF a b b -- T(A,B) = 1+A×B×B
```

These types are polymorphic on A but are fixed points regarding B, something like this:

```
newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }
type List a = Fix (ListF a)
type Tree a = Fix (TreeF a)
```

But as most know, lists and trees are also functors in the usual sense, where they represent a "container" of `a`'s, which you can map a function `f :: a -> b` to get a container of `b`'s.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to make these types (the fixed points) an instance of `Functor` in a generic way, but I'm not sure how. I've encountered the following 2 problems so far:

---

**1)** First, there has to be a way to define a generic `gmap` over any polymorphic fixed point. Knowing that types such as `ListF` and `TreeF` are Bifunctors, so far I've got this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Bifunctor

newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }

cata :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata f = f . fmap (cata f) . unFix

-- To explicitly use inF as the initial algebra
inF :: f (Fix f) -> Fix f
inF = Fix

gmap :: forall a b f. Bifunctor f => (a -> b) -> Fix (f a) -> Fix (f b)
gmap f = cata alg
    where
        alg :: f a (Fix (f b)) -> Fix (f b)
        alg = inF . bimap f id
```

In Haskell this gives me the following error: `Could not deduce (Functor (f a)) arising from a use of cata from the context (Bifunctor f)`.

I'm using the `bifunctors` package, which has a `WrappedBifunctor` type that specifically defines the following instance which could solve the above problem: `Bifunctor p => Functor (WrappedBifunctor p a)`. However, I'm not sure how to "lift" this type inside `Fix` to be able to use it

**2)** Even if the generic `gmap` above can be defined, I don't know if it's possible to create a generic instance of `Functor` that has `fmap = gmap`, and can instantly work for both the `List` and `Tree` types up there (as well as any other type defined in a similar fashion). Is this possible?

If so, would it be possible to make this compatible with `recursion-schemes` too?

Comment: This is your statutory reminder that, as "ADT" stands both for "algebraic data type" and "abstract data type", and as the two notions are violently opposed, the term "ADT" is meaningless and better avoided.

Comment: @pigworker: how about we call them uGADTs from now on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TBH I'm not sure how helpful this solution is to you because it still requires an extra `newtype` wrapping for these fixed-point functors, but here we go:

## You can keep using your generic `cata` if you do some wrapping/unwrapping

Given the following two helper functions:

```
unwrapFixBifunctor :: (Bifunctor f) => Fix (WrappedBifunctor f a) -> Fix (f a)
unwrapFixBifunctor = Fix . unwrapBifunctor . fmap unwrapFixBifunctor . unFix

wrapFixBifunctor :: (Bifunctor f) => Fix (f a) -> Fix (WrappedBifunctor f a)
wrapFixBifunctor = Fix . fmap wrapFixBifunctor . WrapBifunctor . unFix
```

you can define `gmap` without any additional constraint on `f`:

```
gmap :: (Bifunctor f) => (a -> b) -> Fix (f a) -> Fix (f b)
gmap f = unwrapFixBifunctor . cata alg . wrapFixBifunctor
  where
    alg = inF . bimap f id
```

## You can make `Fix . f` into a `Functor` via a `newtype`

We can implement a `Functor` instance for `\a -> Fix (f a)` by implementing this "type-level lambda" as a `newtype`:

```
newtype FixF f a = FixF{ unFixF :: Fix (f a) }

instance (Bifunctor f) => Functor (FixF f) where
    fmap f = FixF . gmap f . unFixF
```

Comment: `bimap f id` should probably be written `Data.Bifunctor.first`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing to accept for the moment you're dealing with bifunctors, you can say

```
cata :: Bifunctor f => (f a r -> r) -> Fix (f a) -> r
cata f = f . bimap id (cata f) . unFix
```

and then

```
gmap :: forall a b f. Bifunctor f => (a -> b) -> Fix (f a) -> Fix (f b)
gmap f = cata alg
    where
        alg :: f a (Fix (f b)) -> Fix (f b)
        alg = inF . bimap f id
```

(In `gmap`, I've just rearranged your class constraint to make scoped type variables work.)

You can also work with your original version of `cata`, but then you need both the
`Functor` and the `Bifunctor` constraint on `gmap`:

```
gmap :: forall a b f. (Bifunctor f, Functor (f a)) => (a -> b) -> Fix (f a) -> Fix (f b)
gmap f = cata alg
    where
        alg :: f a (Fix (f b)) -> Fix (f b)
        alg = inF . bimap f id
```

You cannot make your `gmap` an instance of the normal `Functor` class, because it would need to be something like

```
instance ... => Functor (\ x -> Fix (f x))
```

and we don't have type-level lambda. You *can* do this if you reverse the two arguments of `f`, but then you lose the "other" `Functor` instance and need to define `cata` specific for `Bifunctor` again.

[You might also be interested to read http://www.andres-loeh.de/IndexedFunctors/ for a more general approach.]

Comment: Would it be possible to approach the problem in a different manner, so writing an instance of `Functor` does become possible? Using different types, maybe typeclasses, etc?

Answer (score 1):

The `bifunctors` package also offers a version of `Fix` that's especially appropriate:

```
newtype Fix p a = In {out :: p (Fix p a) a}
```

This is made a `Functor` instance rather easily:

```
instance Bifunctor p => Functor (Fix p) where
  fmap f = In . bimap (fmap f) f . out
```