# Haskell - Functor instance for generic polymorphic Algebraic Data Types using recursion-schemes

Tags: haskell, recursion, functor, algebraic-data-types, category-theory

### Problem:

Recently I asked the following question on here, asking how to create a generic map function, and a generic instance of `Functor` for any arbitrary polymorphic ADT (Algebraic Data Type), like Lists, Trees, etc:

[Functor instance for generic polymorphic ADTs in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856974/functor-instance-for-generic-polymorphic-adts-in-haskell)

Now, I'm trying to reformulate the above to be compatible with `recursion-schemes`. I.e, instead of defining the base functor, and then define the type as its fixed point, I want to define the type on one hand, the base functor on the other, and correlate them using the `Base` family type.

So instead of doing this:

```
data ListF a b = NilF | ConsF a b
newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }
type List a = Fix (ListF a)
```

I want to do this:

```
data ListF a b = NilF | ConsF a b
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
type instance Base (List a) = ListF a
```

This way I could leverage the power of the `recursion-schemes` library, while still being able to define a generic `fmap` for any of these polymorphic types. Not only that, but it's a more pleasant experience being able to use the "normal" type without it being a type synonym for the fix point.

### Attempt:

Initially I thought about having a `Bifunctor` instance on one hand, and somehow coercing or making it equal to the corresponding `Base` family instance. At the moment I can only think about using `a :~: b` from `Data.Type.Equality`. This is what I've got so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, Rank2Types #-}
import Data.Bifunctor
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Type.Equality

gmap :: (Bifunctor p, Foldable (f a), Unfoldable (f b)) => 
        (forall x. p x :~: Base (f x)) -> (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
gmap refl f = cata alg
    where
        alg = embed . 
              castWith (apply refl Refl) . 
              bimap f id . 
              castWith (apply (sym refl) Refl)
```

My problem comes in trying to define an instance of `Functor` though. I don't know how to specify those specific type constraints when defining the instance.
I was thinking about somehow creating a typeclass `Equals`, and doing something like this:

```
instance (Bifunctor p, Foldable (f a), Unfoldable (f b), Equals (p a) (Base (f a))) 
    => Functor f where
```

But I don't know if that's possible, nor if I'm approaching it in the right way (for instance I'm not sure if my definition of `gmap` is the correct one).

---

*For reference, this is the definition of the generic `gmap` from the original SO question:*

```
gmap :: (Bifunctor f) => (a -> b) -> Fix (f a) -> Fix (f b)
gmap f = unwrapFixBifunctor . cata alg . wrapFixBifunctor
  where
    alg = Fix . bimap f id

    unwrapFixBifunctor :: (Bifunctor f) => Fix (WrappedBifunctor f a) -> Fix (f a)
    unwrapFixBifunctor = Fix . unwrapBifunctor . fmap unwrapFixBifunctor . unFix

    wrapFixBifunctor :: (Bifunctor f) => Fix (f a) -> Fix (WrappedBifunctor f a)
    wrapFixBifunctor = Fix . fmap wrapFixBifunctor . WrapBifunctor . unFix
```

---

### Update:

It was noted that the following definition of `gmap` would be more general, and would not need any weird application of type-level equality:

```
gmap :: (Foldable t, Unfoldable d, Bifunctor p, Base d ~ p b, Base t ~ p a)
        => (a -> b) -> t -> d
gmap f = cata ( embed . bimap f id )
```

However, I still can't find a way to create an instance of `Functor` that has similar type constraints

Comment: 1. What is the point of `:~:`? Your function is probably impractical if you have to call it with `Refl` all the time. 2. If I write `gmap f = cata ( embed . bimap f id )` and let the compiler infer the type, I get `(Foldable t, Unfoldable d, Bifunctor p, Base d ~ p b, Base t ~ p a) => (a -> b) -> t -> d`. Is there anything wrong with this most general type? You can have a more specific type if you like. The compiler is perfectly happy with your function, so I don't know what the actual question is.

Comment: @user2405038 I want to create an instance of `Functor` using `fmap = gmap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[With a little help from @kosmikus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067872/477476), I was able to hack together a version that works, as long as you're OK with `UndecidableInstances`.

The idea is to remove all references to `a` and `b` from the context of `gmap`, by requiring `forall x. Foldable (f x)` and so on, encoded using the [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4.1.3) package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeOperators, ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Data.Bifunctor
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Constraint
import Data.Constraint.Forall

-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28067872/477476
class (p x ~ Base (f x)) => Based p f x
instance (p x ~ Base (f x)) => Based p f x

gmap :: forall p f a b. ( Bifunctor p 
                        , ForallF Foldable f
                        , ForallF Unfoldable f
                        , Forall (Based p f))
     => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
gmap f = case (instF :: ForallF Foldable f :- Foldable (f a)) of
  Sub Dict -> case (instF :: ForallF Unfoldable f :- Unfoldable (f b)) of
    Sub Dict -> case (inst :: Forall (Based p f) :- Based p f a) of
      Sub Dict -> case (inst :: Forall (Based p f) :- Based p f b) of
        Sub Dict -> cata (embed . bimap f id)
```

With `a` and `b` out of the way, we can turn `gmap` into `fmap`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
instance (Bifunctor p, ForallF Foldable f, ForallF Unfoldable f, Forall (Based p f)) => Functor f where
    fmap = gmap
```

**Edited to add**: the trouble with the above instance is that it will match any type at the right kind, as noted by @gonzaw: if you have

```
data ListT a = NilT
             | ConsT a (ListT a)

data ListF a b = NilF
               | ConsF a b

type instance Base (ListT a) = ListF a

instance Bifunctor ListF where ...
instance Functor (ListF a) where ...
instance Foldable (ListT a) where ...
instance Unfoldable (ListT a) where ...
```

then you get more than you bargained for, and the generic `Functor` instance and the one for `ListF a`(!) overlap.

You can add one more layer of newtype wrappers to get around that: if instead, you have

```
newtype F f x = F{ unF ::  (f x) }

instance (Bifunctor p, ForallF Foldable f, ForallF Unfoldable f, Forall (Based p f)) => Functor (F f) where
    fmap f = F . gmap f . unF

type ListT' = F ListT
```

then finally the following typechecks:

```
*Main> unF . fmap (+1) . F $ ConsT 1 $ ConsT 2 NilT
ConsT 2 (ConsT 3 NilT)
```

Whether this extra layer of `newtype` wrapping is acceptable for you is something you'll have to decide.

Comment: Awesome! Just a minor quirk though. I'm trying to test this out with a typical List type, like so `data ListT a = ConsT a (ListT a) | NilT`, `data ListF a b = NilF | ConsF a b`, `type instance Base (ListT a) = ListF a`. I create an instance of `Bifunctor`, and when when I try to create an instance `instance Foldable (ListT a) where` I get the following error: `Couldn't match type ‘Base (ListF a Data.Constraint.Forall.A)’ with ‘p1 Data.Constraint.Forall.A’  The type variable p1 is ambiguous`. Idem with `Unfoldable`

Comment: That's because that horrible `Functor` instance matches not just for `ListT`, but also for `ListF`...

Comment: Great, now it works! I don't mind the newtype wrapping. From what I've read, it's a best practice to make these "exotic" automatic kind of instances of common typeclasses (Applicative, Functor, Monad) with a newtype wrapper instead, to prevent orphan instances and the like. I could always just use `gmap` alone when using `ListT`, but if I ever need to use the functionality of `Functor` I'd just wrap and unwrap it quickly. If it bothered me that much, I'd just include a quick `instance Functor ListT where fmap f = unF . fmap f. F` and be done with it

Comment: In fact, I wonder if it's possible to use Template Haskell to include that little  `Functor ListT` instance. That definition would be the same no matter the type. If I have another type, like `TreeT`, it would still be `fmap f = unF . fmap f . F`, right? If so, I think I might try a little bit with that!

Comment: Sorry for triple posting, but would this be a good functionality to include in the recursion-schemes library?

Comment: Of course if you can add hand-written `instance Functor ListT` instances, you might as well set `fmap = gmap` in there, alleviating the need for this generic instance and the `F` newtype wrapper.