# Using Data.Constraint.Forall with equality constraints

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

class C a where

foo :: forall f a b. (C (f a), C (f b)) => f a -> f b
foo = _
```

Now, if I would like to move the scope of `a` and `b` to the right of the typeclass constraint in the type of `foo` (let's say, because I want to use `foo` to implement a typeclass method that needs to be polymorphic in `a` and `b`), it can done with a bit of legwork using `Data.Constraint.Forall`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Constraint
import Data.Constraint.Forall

foo' :: forall f. (ForallF C f) => forall a b. f a -> f b
foo' = helper
  where
    helper :: forall a b. f a -> f b
    helper = case (instF :: ForallF C f :- C (f a)) of
        Sub Dict -> case (instF :: ForallF C f :- C (f b)) of
            Sub Dict -> foo
```

Now, my question is, suppose I change my function to something involving type equalities:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

type family F a :: * -> *

bar :: forall f g a b. (F (f a) ~ g a, F (f b) ~ g b) => f a -> f b
bar = _
```

Is there a way to adapt the above technique to this?

Here's what I tried:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Constraint
import Data.Constraint.Forall

type F'Eq f g x = F (f x) ~ g x

bar' :: forall f g. (Forall (F'Eq f g)) => forall a b. f a -> f b
bar' = helper
  where
    helper :: forall a b. f a -> f b
    helper = case (inst :: Forall (F'Eq f g) :- F'Eq f g a) of
        Sub Dict -> case (inst :: Forall (F'Eq f g) :- F'Eq f g b) of
            Sub Dict -> bar
```

But (unsurprisingly) this fails because of the unsaturated type synonym:

> Type synonym `‘F'Eq’` should have 3 arguments, but has been given 2
>
> In an expression type signature: `Forall (F'Eq f g) :- F'Eq f g a`
>
> In the expression: `(inst :: Forall (F'Eq f g) :- F'Eq f g a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

class (F (f x) ~ g x) => F'Eq f g x
instance (F (f x) ~ g x) => F'Eq f g x

bar' :: forall f g. (Forall (F'Eq f g)) => forall a b. f a -> f b
bar' = helper
  where
    helper :: forall a b. f a -> f b
    helper = case (inst :: Forall (F'Eq f g) :- F'Eq f g a) of
        Sub Dict -> case (inst :: Forall (F'Eq f g) :- F'Eq f g b) of
            Sub Dict -> bar
```